# Bind document.ready to a popout window

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Due to the manner in which jQuery binds the `document.ready` event, code that should be simple isn't:

```
var w = window.open(someSameOriginLocation,'');
$(w).ready(function () { //alternatively selector could be $(w.document)
  console.log('popout ready');
});
```

#### Problems

- the callback executes when the parent window is ready, not the child
- within the callback `this` is a reference to `w.opener.document`

Is there a reasonably simple, cross-browser way of binding the `ready` event (or similar) to a different window context using jQuery?

Comment: Perhaps with jQuery .live function and 'load' event

Comment: @HerrSerker, `live` just binds events to the active `document`. I'm fine with using a custom binding function like `$(w).popupready(fn);`, I'm just trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I asked this question about 5 years ago I hadn't heard of promises. jQuery 1.7 had recently been released, and `Deferred` had been introduced in 1.5 earlier in the year. This predated the `Promises/A+` specification, which was released just over a year later.

I say this all because at the time I had no way of recognizing jQuery's `$(document).ready(...)` for what it was.

It was bound as an event, and took a callback as an event, and the jQuery API treated it as an event, so I had mistakenly assumed it was an event, albeit a special one.

*Document ready is not an event.* **It's a promise.**

So with all that said, my mistake was in attempting to follow jQuery's lead and create a fancy event, when what I should have done was use a promise (never mind that they didn't exist in the JS world yet).

---

With all that said, supporting a `document.ready`-like behavior on any window reference in modern browsers is pretty simple. I have the advantage of time in that many old problems have been bugfixed away, and new browser features (such as `Promise`) greatly reduce the amount of effort to implement a `ready` function.

My solution to this problem looks like:

```
function ready(win) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        function checkReady() {
            if (win.document.readyState === 'complete') {
                resolve();
            }
        }

        win.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkReady, false);
        win.addEventListener('load', checkReady, false);
        checkReady();
    });
}
```

and can be used as:

```
ready(window).then(function () {
  //...do stuff
});
```

or if you're using `window.open`:

```
ready(open('/your/file.html', ...)).then(function () {
  //.../your/file.html is ready
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The JavaScript security policy won't allow this. For example you get console error

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.example.com/ from frame with URL http://www.example.org/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

---

It's necessary that you have a pause between the calling of window.open and setting of the onload function of that same window. Immediately after the window.open call that window has no properties. Perhaps you must do this with setInterval repeatedly (don't forget the clearInterval then)
Try this in jsfiddle (this is my best guess)

```
function func() {

    var w = window.open('http://fiddle.jshell.net/','windowname');

    setTimeout(function() {
        w.onload = function () {
            $(w).ready(function() {
                console.log(w.name)
            });
        };
    },1000)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/fTjTr/8/

Comment: You need to brush up on your security sandbox knowledge. A page is granted access to child pages of the same domain ([same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) in addition to any non-content pages. You can't change the location to `http://www.example.com/'` and expect it to work. My example code runs just fine (apart from `ready` not binding to the right window context).

Comment: @zzzzBov Your code does not run, because you don't load any page. So no DOMready will fire. I didn't know you are in the same domain. Then why don't you fire `$(document).ready` from within the loaded window and rely to `window.opener.document`?

Comment: You have obviously missed the point of the question. `window.open('','')` could be `window.open('foo.html')` and I would like the parent page to have a callback for when the loaded page (empty or not) is fully ready. I've been examining the jQuery source, and it doesn't look it'll be *too* difficult to create my own generic event, I was just hoping someone else already had.

Comment: setting a single `onload` event is nowhere near the capabilities of a `document.ready` call in jQuery.

Comment: The changes you made were lipstick on a pig. You didn't change any of the core issues with your script, and in fact made it worse because you have a fundamental lack of understanding of how jQuery manages the `.ready()` function.

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't know what the problem is here. It fairly is not, how jQuery handles the `.ready()` function, but how the browsers handle, when you have a proper `window` object and when you have a proper `window.document` object in the new window. That seems to be the problem here

Comment: I already mentioned above that your code only allows a binding a single event to body onload, which is not the onreadystatechange or equivalent event. It does not unbind itself post-call, it simply *isn't* an answer. At this point I've ceased to be interested in discussing this issue with you because you've continually created worse code and not solved any of the issues in my initial question.

Comment: If you want to get a solution served on a silver plate, than go and pay someone for it. This is getting way too personal. Just trying to help.